# Avoid Antivirus AVG using too much CPU to check a Python script

Tags: cpu, python, anti-virus, pycharm, exceptions

I am currently developing a Python script that performs some http requests and uses a webdriver. When I run the script from Pycharm, AVG starts performing some sort of scanning that reduces the performance of my PC, using more CPU than the script itself.
[image: cpu usage]

What type of exclusion should I insert inside of AVG in order to let everything launched throught Pycharm to be excluded from scanning?

Comment: Create an exception for your python script or the entire folder the script exists in within AVG.  You can also request an Administrator temporarily disable AVG

Comment: @Ramhound I put as an exception all the PycharmProjects folder, but that didn't work

Comment: Try Pycharm and Python bin folders also

Comment: @Ramhound I put as expection the following folders: C:\Program Files\Jetbrains\ (Pycharm folder), C:\Python310\, C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\, C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\, but still not working

Comment: The problem seems to be related  to both behavior protection and ransomware protection AVG modules

Comment: Sounds like an AVG issue. I don’t say that to dismiss your problem but if creating exceptions don’t prevent the CPU usage from increasing then that’s a defect in AVG.